# How to choose Content-Type in HTTP response

Tags: http, content-type

I write small http server. I need to set Content-Type when I send file in response. How it should be done? Should Content-Type field be preset in some map for each file or it might be set basing on file extension? If yes, how about `*.ico` files that are `PNG` actually?

So what’s the common practice?

Comment: What language are you using to build http server. For most languages there should be some package which implements this functionality. For npm/node there is https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types

Comment: C++. Learning project so please don't say it's a bad choice ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what’s the common practice?

Common practice, for static files, is to infer the Content-Type from the file extension.

> If yes, how about *.ico files that are PNG actually?

Then common practice would give the wrong content-type.

You could override it on a case-by-case basis from a configuration file.

e.g. Apache HTTPD would allow:

```
<Files "favicon.ico">
    ForceType image/png
</Files>
```